# Prove that the ideal $(x^3 + x + 1)$ in the polynomial ring $Z/(2)[x]$ over $Z/(2)$ is a prime ideal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

There are two ways to prove this and in both ways I have not been able to:
Let $A,B$ ideals in $Z/(2)[x]$ if $AB\subseteq (x^3 + x + 1)$ and $B\nsubseteq(x^3 + x + 1)$ 
I do not know how to prove that $A\subseteq (x^3 + x + 1)$. 
The other way is by proving that $Z/(2)[x]/(x^3 + x + 1)$ is simple, for it let $C+(x^3 + x + 1)$ ideals in $Z/(2)[x]/(x^3 + x + 1)$ and $C+(x^3 + x + 1)\neq (0)$ 
How can I prove that $C+(x^3 + x + 1)=Z/(2)[x]/(x^3 + x + 1)$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simpler way is to prove that $x^3 + x + 1$ is irreducible mod $2$, and this is easy because it does not have a root.

Comment: @Ihf How do I prove it to be irreducible? 
And why testing this is ready?

Comment: @Nash, it does not have a root mod 2.

Comment: Yes, And why testing this is ready?

Comment: @Nash, the only possible roots are $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Yes, thank you!

Comment: @Ihf Then for show  that the ideal $(x^3 -x-1)$ in the polynomial ring $Z/(3)[x]$ over the field $Z/(3)$ is a maximal ideal and therefore, prime. Do I proceed in the same way?

Comment: @Nash, ask a separate question.